# Getting error "The name 'productService' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im getting the error "**The name 'productService' does not exist in the current context**" in my Telerik Kendo grid:

```
namespace Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Controllers
{
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Editing_Popup()
    {
        //ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        return View();
    }

     public ActionResult EditingPopup_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(productService.Read().ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EditingPopup_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ProductViewModel product)
    {
        if (product != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            productService.Create(product);
        }
        return Json(new[] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EditingPopup_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ProductViewModel product)
    {
        if (product != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            productService.Update(product);
        }
        return Json(new[] {product}.ToDataSourceResult(request,ModelState));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EditingPopup_Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ProductViewModel product)
    {
        if (product != null)
        {
            productService.Destroy(product);
        }
        return Json(new[] { product }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you injecting productService? I dont see it in your code.

Comment: i dont know injecting productservice i want this dependency injecting code for Create, Read,Update,Delete

Comment: Where did you get this code from? Basically you need to initialize the productService object at class level. DI is better way to achieve loose coupling in short.

Answer (score 1):

I would start looking into **Dependency Injection/IOC**. Some examples of this are [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) and [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/). There is information on each of those sites to help you get started. The idea is that you have fields on your controller for your dependencies, which in turn are passed into the constructor and set there, so any dependency you need will be there on creation of the controller.

For a simple, self rolled dependency injection solution, you could have a class which instatiates all of your singletons and all of your controllers, passing in all of the relevant dependencies from there. And in your application start, register said class.

**Global.asax Application Start**

```
 CompositionRoot = new CompositionRoot(); 
            HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(CompositionRoot);
            config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), CompositionRoot);
            var apiAuthenticationProvider = new ApiAuthenticationProvider(new HashGenerator());
            config.Services.Add(typeof(System.Web.Http.Filters.IFilterProvider), new BasicAuthenticationFilterProvider(apiAuthenticationProvider));
```

**Composition Root**

```
public sealed class CompositionRoot :IDisposable, IHttpControllerActivator, IControllerFactory
{
    // Singleton-scoped services are declared here...
    private readonly SingletonType_singletonInstance;
    public CompositionRoot()
    {
        // intitialise any application instance singletons
        _singletonInstance = new SingletonType()
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        // Per-Request-scoped services are declared and initialized here
        if (controllerType == typeof(TestController))
        {
            return new TestController(_singletonInstance)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've not got a member field or local variable named 'productService'.  You have to declare it like this:

```
var productService = new ProductService();
```

or as a field on the class:

```
private ProductService productService = new ProductService();
```

before you can use it.

Here's an MSDN about fields: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173118(v=vs.80).aspx

I would also recommend that you read this from the beginning as it teaches a lot of the basics that will stop you struggling as you progress: http://www.csharp-station.com/tutorial.aspx